# URL to access a defect directly in Quality Center 10

Tags: bug-tracking, hp-quality-center

How can I create a direct link to a Defect in Quality Center 10?

In the QC UI when I right click on a defect, i see an option "Copy URL". Which gives me a URL similar to

```
td://[ProjectName].[Domail].[Host]:8080/qcbin/Defects?Action=FindDefect&DefectID=[Defect ID]
```

but when I paste this URL in IE, it does not show anything. Is there some other setting or option that needs to be turned ON for this to work?

If I have all the above details i.e. ProjectName, Domain, HostName & Defect ID can I create this URL manually (outside QC UI) and use it?

EDITED:

I was able to get this to work i.e. the link to work by:

1. Open RUN window by WinKey + r
2. type: iexplore  and press enter.

This opens a new IE window and opens QC. Asks the User to login if not already and opens the UI with focus on the defect identified by the Defect ID.

Is there a way to get this to work from a Web Page Hyperlink which is being viewed from another browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

td:// is a custom protocol which is handled by a custom protocol handler deployed by QC on first load of QC client.

It is supposed to work both from IE address bar, from run dialog (no need to enter iexplore) and as a link in email or on a webpage.

This is true as long as QC client is deployed on your machine, and the rest of IE is configured correctly to allow QC client to run in it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way we can use this as a URL from a web page? Potentially open in Firefox? I note that I tried using this URL in <a> tag and opened that web page in IE, the link did not work in than.

Comment: I have created this simple html: <html>
<body>
<a href="td://project.domain.server:8080/qcbin/DefectsModule-000000004243046514?EntityType=IBug&EntityID=1">link<a>
</body>
</html> and opened it in firefox locally (not from server) and clicked the link. Firefox asked me if I want to allow HP ALM to run, once I said yes, it opened QC. This is with HP ALM 11, supposed to work the same for QC 10

Comment: If it does not work, it's most likely related to security settings of the machine.

Comment: I do not know what has happened or what idiotic stuff I had been doing, but now for some reason the example that I had pasted in the question itself has started working. Thanks Alex for you responses.

Answer (score -1):

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TestDirector\shell\open\command` needs to have the following key value : `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\HP\ALM-Client\server\TdComandProtocol.exe "/start_a.jsp" "%1"`

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TD\shell\open\command` needs to have the following key value : `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\HP\ALM-Client\server\TdComandProtocol.exe "/start_a.jsp" "%1"`